# Epoch millis kibana mapping 1970 year problem

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Im new to ELK Stack and i am facing this problem. Whenever i try to map timestamp from csv file (im mapping in kibana with epoch_millis) in my field all the dates start with  18january 1970, not the year of the timestamp. How can I get rid of this  or should I map it differently? Should I do something in the logstash? I am aware od that that this epoch have something to do with this 1970 year, but is there any other way to map this type of timestamp 1545003901 ?

Comment: Share your mapping, the pipeline that you are using to ingest the data and a sample of your csv so people can look into that and try to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Replace datatype "epoch_milis"(default type for date) in your mapping with "date".
More here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

Comment: In my mappings I have : "type": "date"   "format": "epoch_millis" for the timestamp field. Already did that.. Do you say that I need to delete the format?

Comment: You can choose from formats here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html